# Get an array of results of a function using as input an array of values (in Matlab)

Tags: matlab, anonymous-function

I want to get the array of results of a function using as input an array of values. The function receives two variables (x1, x2) and a constant x3, so I'm trying to input all combination of it in a range using mesh.

The result is incorrect, I'm missing something.

Sample:

```
fun = @(x1,x2,x3) (x2-x1^2)^2+(1-x1)^2 + x3;
x3 = 7;
fun2 = @(x) fun(x(1,1),x(1,2),x3);

x0 = [2 3];
min = fminsearch(fun2, x0);
disp(min);

x = min(1)-10:1:min(1)+10;
y = min(2)-10:1:min(2)+10;

[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);

% I'm getting strange values here, like z < 0, how it is possible if everything is squared in the function.
Z = fun(X,Y,x3);
```

Comment: My guess: you should be using element-wise operations, e.g. `.^` instead of the matrix operations, e.g., `^`, when defining `fun`.

Comment: LOL, done... Thanks. I think you should write it as an answer.

Comment: Glad it was helpful. Posted as answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's important to note that there is a difference between [matrix and element-wise operations in MATLAB](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/array-vs-matrix-operations.html).

Matrix operations are defined via plain operators, such as `*`, or `^`. So for example, `A*B` performs a matrix multiplication between `A` and `B`.

Element-wise operators make use of the dot `.` before the operator, i.e., `.*`, `.^`, and so on. Thus, `A.*B` performs an element-wise multiplication of `A` and `B`. The end result of this operation is an array of the same size as `A` and `B` (whose sizes must be equal), where the `jj`'th element of the array is equal to `A(jj)*B(jj)`.

Now, consider your definition of `fun`:

```
fun = @(x1,x2,x3) (x2-x1^2)^2+(1-x1)^2 + x3;
```

What happens when MATLAB evaluates this expression is that it applies the matrix operations, such as `^` to the input arrays. However, to obtain your desired result of applying the operation to every individual element in your input arrays `x1`, `x2`, you should be using element-wise operations.

A new definition

```
fun = @(x1,x2,x3) (x2-x1.^2).^2+(1-x1).^2 + x3;
```

should provide the desired result.